# upgrading Bugzilla getting error table already exists

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, bugzilla

After importing old database, I am running .checksetup.pl but i am getting below error.

I am using debian 8 OS

Bugzilla upgrading version 5.0.3

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Table 'audit_log' already exists [for Statement "CREATE TABLE audit_log (
    user_id mediumint,
    class   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    object_id       integer NOT NULL,
    field   varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    removed mediumtext,
    added   mediumtext,
    at_time datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8"] at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 837.
    Bugzilla::DB::_bz_add_table_raw(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x2c22c10), "audit_log", HASH(0x7bb03f0)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 796
    Bugzilla::DB::bz_add_table(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x2c22c10), "audit_log", HASH(0x7bb03f0)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 509
    Bugzilla::DB::bz_setup_database(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x2c22c10)) called at Bugzilla/DB/Mysql.pm line 558
    Bugzilla::DB::Mysql::bz_setup_database(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x2c22c10)) called at ./checksetup.pl line 121
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 121 of checksetup.pl is trying to create the tables again. I suggest you to export bugzilla DB, then drop bugzilla DB, run checksetup.pl again and it will create your tables all over again. Then import your data back into the DB.

> 120 #Create the tables, and do any database-specific schema changes.
>
> 121 $dbh->bz_setup_database();

Please let me know if it doesn't help you.